# How can I extract the functionality of a OOB Web Part?

Tags: visual-web-part

OK, this is my question... I need to extract the functionality of the My Links web part and later use it in a new custom web part. If you know how can I do, just say it.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Since [SummaryLinkWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.summarylinkwebpart.aspx) is [sealed class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) you cannot inherit from it. This means you need to develop your own custom web part from scratch with same functionalities.

You can use some decompiler like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to examine original code **but (!)** keep in mind [legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler#Legality) and also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109357/is-it-legal-to-make-code-decompiled-from-net-libraries-publicly-available).

Comment: As Vedran said, Summary Links is sealed and it is huge in terms of its size. But if you let us know how to you want to customize, may be it could be achieved without extending it.